# Entity Framework 4.1 - What does RequiredAttribute really mean?

Tags: c#, data-annotations, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having a database computed field in my Code-First model. I've marked that with the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute. Do I need to specify the RequiredAttribute too?

In other words: Does 'required' mean, that it's required this value is assigned to? Or does it mean, that this value is not allowed to be null.

Comment: Not nullable, I believe.

Comment: My guess that it affects validation only. Nullable or not depends on type (int or int?). (But it's just a guess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequiredAttribute` is used for both validation and mapping definition. If you define `string` property without this attribute it is defined as nullable column in the database but with this attribute it is not nullabe. In other words it says if property can contain `null` both during validation and in the database.

Comment: What would that mean for 'DatabaseGenerated' properties? From my point of view, such a value would always be null for newly created entities (even while validation) before they were committed into the database. And second question is, do we need to use Nullable<> types or is it sufficient to only msis the 'Required'-Attribute?